# focus a table cell on click - jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css, html-table

I have an HTML table,

when any cell is clicked, I want to highlight that cell using css, until another cell is clicked

I thought, I will set focus for that cell and set css for focus

but its not working..

my code goes as below:

```
$('td').click(function (event) {
    //$(this).tabindex = 0; 
    //$(this).tabindex = 1;
    $(this).focus();
});
```

and css as follows

```
td:focus
{
    background-color:Blue;
}
```

I think, I can't add class to `td` because when other cell clicked I have to remove this class then..

Please help me achieve my requirement.

Also please let me know if there is any other way of achieving this or any work arounds..

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try:

```
$('td').click(function (event) {
      $('td').removeClass('focus'); //Remove focus from other TDs
     $(this).addClass('focus');
});
```

And

> td.focus {
>       background-color:Blue; }

Answer (score 2):

For starters, `:focus` is used for form `input` fields, I doubt it can be applied to any other elements. You should use your own class:

JS:

```js
$('td').click(function (event) {
    $('*').removeClass('focus');
    $(this).addClass('focus');
});
```

CSS:

```css
td.focus {
    background-color:Blue;
}
```

This way focusing a `td` will unfocus anything else that might have the `.focus` class, then set it on the selected element.

You could also do:

```js
$('*').click(function(event){
    $(this).removeClass('focus');
});
$('td').click(function (event) {
    $(this).addClass('focus');
});
```

So clicking on anything will un-focus a focused td (similar behaviour to how :focus works  on input fields or how :active works on anchor tags)

Answer (score 1):

if you want to keep them "focused" until you click again you could use the handy toggleClass function

see fiddle example here: http://jsfiddle.net/eVS9f/5/

```
$("td").click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("focus");
    });
```

Comment: Thats not what he needs: `when other cell clicked I have to remove this class then..`

Comment: i understand, just showing toggleClass with a jsfiddle working example to illustrate that click-on/click-off alternative, when i finished my jsfiddle example your answer was already posted, so i changed it to toggle and posted to add more info in this thread